# Carnot Engine question

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

While writing the efficiency of the Carnot engine the numerator part contains the work done by the system which is performed while the system is taken through isothermal and adiabatic expansion, but we write the net work performed in the numerator, why is that so?

Comment: The idea is to find how much of the heat you put in gets converted to a useful form, ie how much work your system can perform using the heat you put in.

Answer (score 5):

> but we write the net work performed in the numerator, why is that so?

Because the thermal efficiency $\eta$ of any heat engine cycle, Carnot or otherwise, equals the net work done $W_{net}$ over the cycle divided by the gross heat input, $Q_{H}$ or

$$\eta=\frac{W_{net}}{Q_H}$$

For conservation of energy over any heat engine cycle, the net work done equals the heat added minus the heat rejected. So for any heat engine

$$W_{net}=Q_{H}-Q_C$$

And therefore

$$\eta=\frac{Q_{H}-Q_C}{Q_H}$$

For the Carnot cycle the heat added and rejected occurs during the reversible isothermal expansion and compression, respectively, and $Q_{H}=T_{H}\Delta S$ and $Q_{C}=T_{C}\Delta S$. Thus for the Carnot cycle

$$\eta=\frac{T_{H}\Delta S-T_{C}\Delta S}{T_{H}\Delta S}=1-\frac{T_{C}}{T_{H}} $$

Hope  this helps.